# how to include a component in another module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component named `barchar`.

There is another module component `src\app\modules\dashboard\page` and this file has module file.

but `barchzt` does not have the module.

how to use `barchzt` in the `src\app\modules\dashboard\page\home-page\home-page.component.html` ?

I tried to to include the selector `<app-barchart></app-barchart>` in
`src\app\modules\dashboard\page\home-page\home-page.component.html` but I'm getting the following error:

`'app-barchart' is not a known element`

Comment: Where did you provide the component `barchar`? Also, are you trying to use `barchar` in multiple modules? A `component` can only be declared in one module only, si if this is the case you can just create a `Shared` module and provide it in every other module you want (Be sure to `export` the components as well).

Comment: Register the component in the `dashboard` module. if you will be sharing certain component with different modules, it is good approach to create a shared module and export the component.

Answer (score 0):

import you barchzt component in your app.module, Then in the app module type the name of the barchzt component in declarations